# c++ 14 (VS 2015) shared_ptr with protected inheritance - no suitable user defined conversion

Tags: c++, c++14, shared-ptr, protected

I'm getting a strange compilation error when using shared pointer with protected inheritance. The below simple code doesn't compile and gives error "no suitable user defined conversion"  but it works with public inheritance. Not sure why, could anyone please explain?

```
class ioptionpricer
{
public:
    virtual std::shared_ptr<ioptionpricer> clone() const = 0;
    virtual void doSomething() const = 0;
    virtual ~ioptionpricer() = default;
};

class optionpricer : protected ioptionpricer
{
public:
    std::shared_ptr<ioptionpricer> clone() const
    {
        return std::make_shared<optionpricer>(*this);
    }
};
```

Comment: You forgot to post the exact error messages. One of them must be `error: allocating an object of abstract class type 'optionpricer'`. If you fix this error, the code compiles of the public inheritance. With the protected inheritance you get the protected copy constructor.

Comment: Why would you use `protected` inheritance here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the inheritance is private (or protected) then one cannot cast `derived*` to `base*` outside of the class (or derived classes for protected inheritance).

In case of conversion from `shared_ptr<derived>` to `shared_ptr<base>`, the conversion from `derived*` to `base*` happens somewhere in implementation of the template `shared_ptr<T>`. So, with private/protected inheritance it won't fly. Unless you declare `shared_ptr` to be a friend.

Either way just use `public` inheritance in these situations, it is pointless to make it private or protected in such situations.